# Facebook Post Alert - February 2013 Breaking Changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, alert

Iam working on a rails application and using [FBGraph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) to post on Facebook. The facebook post happens when a person clicks on a Want button. Iam using the following code to post on a user's wall:

```
if facebook_post.user.granted_publish_actions?
  me = FbGraph::User.me(facebook_post.user.oauth_token)
  me.feed!(
    :picture => facebook_post.picture_url,
    :link => facebook_post.link,
    :name => facebook_post.name,
    :description =>facebook_post.description
    ) 
end
```

This code doesn't call Open Graph API to post on a user's wall. But still my app got the [alert](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013) which is basically a warning for the apps that call Open Graph API to post on user's wall.

Please advice if Iam missing something.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert is sent because your app setting for "February 2013 Breaking Changes" is disabled. If you have nothing to modify, just go to app's Advanced setting page and enable this.
The URL for setting page is something like "https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/advanced"

Comment: I enabled the settings but now Login with facebook has started giving me the  error - "An error occurred. Please try again later.". Iam not using Open Graph ApI. what am I missing? Please help.

Comment: That's a bug redirecting Auth Dialog's legacy URL to a wrong URL. Now the bug should be fixed. The detail is here. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/604938429520244